# Graph API to get list of chats with $filter=id eq 'chat-id' is not working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have recently observed a strange behavior in the Graph API to get chat by id.
The following graph call works fine and gives the response.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/19:b8577894a63548969c5c92bb9c80c5e1@thread.v2
However, if I call the graph API with the filter expression like below it doesn't return any response for the same chat id
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats?$filter=id eq '19:b8577894a63548969c5c92bb9c80c5e1@thread.v2'

This again doesn't return empty for all chat-id's, the chats that were not been active for few months are returned empty. However, if we post some message or add/remove member or basically modify something in the chat, the graph call with $filter=id eq 'chat-id' returns the response properly.

The graph call with https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/19:b8577894a63548969c5c92bb9c80c5e1@thread.v2
returns response even for the inactive chats

Comment: We are also able to repro this issue, we will check internally and get back to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While using below Graph call, you will get a nextLink and you gotta keep following it. After you click on that link for 3-4 times, it will give you the response.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats?$filter=id eq '19:b8577894a63548969c5c92bb9c80c5e1@thread.v2'
```

[image]

Also please note that using above query is inefficient way of fetching one chat and hence if you know chatId, https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/19:b8577894a63548969c5c92bb9c80c5e1@thread.v2 should be used.

Comment: I am using this approach because I want to pass more than one chatid and get all chat responses, like 12 - 14 id's

Comment: @MaheSHYU - Engineering team has said that it is an inefficient way of fetching chat.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I would like to know your suggestion to fetch multiple chats data by passing list of chatIds

Comment: @MaheSHYU - You can use [batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching) for this. Sharing an example below for your reference - https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GpOk.png

Comment: Thanks for the response, is there any other way than batch call? I suspect sometimes the batch call might not return response for all the calls in the batch

Comment: Unfortunately there is no other way. We can only use batch API for this scenario.